# Cryptographically secure RNG in C++ for RSA PKCS#1 (key generation)

Tags: c++, random, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to re-implement the RSA key generation in C++ (as a hobby/learning playground) and by far my biggest problem seems to be *generating a random number in range x,y which is also cryptographically secure* (the primes p and q, for example).

I suppose using mt19937 or std::rand with a secure random seed (e.g. /dev/urandom or OpenSSL RAND_bytes etc) would not be considered 'cryptographically secure' in this case (RSA)?

[ISAAC](https://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/isaacafa.html) looked promising but I have zero clue on how to use it since I wasn't able to find any documentation at all.

Notably, this is also my first C++ project (I've done some C, Rust etc before... So C++ at least feels somewhat familiar and I'm not a complete newbie, mind you).

Comment: You don't need a pseudo-random number generator. Just fetch as many bytes as you need from /dev/urandom or rand_bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suppose using mt19937 or std::rand with a secure random seed (e.g. /dev/urandom or OpenSSL RAND_bytes etc) would not be considered 'cryptographically secure' in this case (RSA)?

No, those are not cryptographically secure for basically any purpose.

> ISAAC looked promising but I have zero clue on how to use it since I wasn't able to find any documentation at all.

Well, it stood the time I suppose. But I'd simply use a C++ library such as Crypto++ or Botan or something similar and then just implement the RSA key pair generation bit, borrowing one of their secure random generators. With a bit of luck they also have a `bignum` library so that you don't have to implement that either.

Comment: After looking around a little bit more, I figured I'd just use /dev/urandom for my CSRNG and GMP as my BigInt library. Thanks for pointing out some more libraries and answering my question :)

Comment: Using `/dev/urandom` is fine from a cryptographic point of view (assuming that the implementation is correct) but maybe not from a portability point of view. That OK if you don't care for that :)